# Can't get usermanager ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-identity

I need some help about my ASP.NET Core project.

I need the connected user to create an object. The problem is I can't get the User manager.

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1. I've seen some people use `ApplicationUser`, and if possible, I don't want to use it. Thanks :)

First I tried to use userManager, but get an error, userManager was null. So I tried to fix it, and I can't create a userManager object,

> Error CS7036
> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
> parameter 'store' of 'UserManager<IdentityUser.UserManager(IUserStore<IdentityUser>, IOptions<IdentityOptions>, IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser>, IEnumerable<IUserValidator<IdentityUser>>, IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<IdentityUser>>, ILookupNormalizer, IdentityErrorDescriber, IServiceProvider, ILogger<UserManager<IdentityUser>>)'"

Comment: Can you show your code about `asp.net-core-identity` in Startup.cs ? I mean it's hard for us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()'

Comment: Hi, sorry Im a bit late but I am facing the same problem right now. Have you found any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

According to your hint, my controller code is as below, after logging in the user, and testing my method, I didn't get the kind of error like you got.

**MyController**

```
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger,  UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _userManager = userManager;

}
public IActionResult Test1()
{
    var appUser =  _userManager.FindByNameAsync(
     HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    return Json(new { data = appUser.Result.Email });
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
...
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

**Test Result:**

[image]